equality of inner product and derivative
I came across the following claim
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \dfrac{f(rx) - f(0)}{r} = \langle v,x \rangle$$
locally uniformly implies that the derivative of $f$ at $0$ exists and $Df(0) = v$.
I don't follow how this holds, the definition of the derivative at $a$ is an operator $Df(a)$ satisfying
$$\lim_{r\to a} \dfrac{|f(r)-f(a)-Df(a)|r-a||}{|a-r|} = 0$$
on the other hand,
$$\langle v,x \rangle = |v| |x| \cos \theta$$
What am I missing?

Your definition of the derivative is not correct (at least not in dimensions higher than $1$). On the other hand, if you are in dimension $1$, then $\langle v, x \rangle = v\cdot x$ (i.e. just multiplication).

Let $\epsilon >0$. There exists $\delta>0$ such that $|\frac{f(rx) - f(0)}{r} - \langle v,x \rangle| <\epsilon$ for $0 <r<\delta$ whenever $\|x\|=1$ ($\delta$ independent of $x$). Let $y\ne 0$. Put $r=\|y\|$ and $x=\frac x {\|x||}$. If $\|y\|<\delta$ we get $|\frac{f(y) - f(0)}{\|y\|} - \frac 1 {\|y\|}\langle v,y \rangle| <\epsilon$. By definition, this  says that $Df(0)$ is the linear map which send $y$ to $ \langle v, y \rangle$ (identified with the  vector $v$).
